# Gradle gretty plugin:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when dependencies with mulit level project

Tags: gradle, gretty

When i use gretty to start my spring boot project , i got a NoClassDefFoundError,the project is structured as follows.ProjectA is a simple webapp project,ProjectB and ProjectC is simple java project.

```
projectA:

@RestController
public class AController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/print",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String print(){
        new BClass().print();
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

gretty{
    springBoot = true
    port = 8080
    contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'tomcat8'
    managedClassReload = true
}

dependencies{

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"

    compile project(":projectB")

}

ProjectB:

public class BClass {
    public void print(){
        new CClass().print();
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }
}

dependencies{
    compile project(":projectC")
}

ProjectC:

public class CClass {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

start command:

```
gradle :projectA:appRun
```

then access : http://localhost:8080/print
I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project/c/CClass
it seems to be the ProjectA concise reference the class of ProjectC,and gretty how not include ProjectC to classpath.
How can i do for this?thanks

gretty plugin :https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help but I can confirm that I get the same problem. I'm also using Spring Boot as you are and wonder if that's part of the problem.